# Query two databases using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have the following in my controller get method

```
private PeopleContext Peopledb = new PeopleContext();
private IARContext db = new IARContext();

    public ActionResult OwnerList()
    {        
        var owners = from s in db.Owners
                     where s.Dormant == false
                     orderby s.Post.PostName
                     select s;

        var viewModel = owners.Select(t => new OwnerListViewModel
        {
             Created = t.Created,
             Post = Peopledb.Posts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PostId == t.SelectedPostId).PostName.ToString(),
        });
        return PartialView("_OwnerList", viewModel);
    }
```

I'm getting this error when I try and load the page:

> The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.

I know the issue is that LINQ cant query two different contexts but having tried several solutions on here I cant seem to fix the issue and sucesfully query the Peopledb.Posts table to find the related PostName to display for each instance in the db.Owners table.

Comment: Are they on the same server?  Create a view or a synonym in IAR to get you the table you need in People.

Comment: And if they are not on the same server, linked servers may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var owners = (from s in db.Owners
                     where s.Dormant == false
                     orderby s.Post.PostName
                     select s).ToList();
```

This will execute the code in one `context` and have the `List<Owner>` in memory for the other `context`.

Also take a look for the execution of the `.Select` part, does it execute a separate query for each `owner`? If so you should optimize it, you can get the `posts` beforehand using the `ids` and then build your `viewmodel`.

Comment: Having added this I now get Object reference not set to an instance of an object. no the Post within the viewModel

Comment: I believe the error is in the `.Select`, it seems you don't have matching records, you can either just get the `post` object (which will be null in some cases) or you can do a `left join` or you can check with `.Any()` before doing the `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: I discovered an issue with the saving of owners itwasnt passing the PostId correctly which has solved the second problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework context can work only with single database. If you want to get data from another database in this context, you can create proxy View, that will reflect this data in db of your `dbcontext`.

Comment: Just to clarify do you mean have a linked server and on the db have a view which contains the data so it can be accessed from the dbcontext

Comment: He has two contexts though, which is acceptable. However, he is referencing one from within the other, which is what is causing issues. I believe AD.Net's answer to be correct, in that he needs to convert the first one into a List() to force it to query the DB at that point and cache it in memory.

Comment: In this case he will use more memory.

Answer (score 0):

Just transition from Linq-to-Entities to Linq-to-Objects using `AsEnumerable()`:

```
    var viewModel = owners.AsEnumerable()
                          .Select(t => new OwnerListViewModel
    ...
```